# want to compare user input time with my sqlite table time column in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to compare user input time with my sqlite table time column like 
where user input time store in
hour_x,minute x

```
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
              hour_x = hourOfDay;
              minute_x = minute;
              settime.setText(hour_x+":"+minute_x);
        }
```

and i have many time column in table like

```
hellodb4.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (STATION TEXT,TIME TIME,TIME TIME,TIME TIME)");
hellodb4.execSQL("INSERT INTO time_table  VALUES ('STN1','03:35','03:55','03:57');");
hellodb4.execSQL("INSERT INTO time_table  VALUES ('STN2','06:30','06:55','06:57');");
```

SO
I want to compare like when user select any time then it should compare with All 'TIME' column as user_input time>='TIME' Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String yourDate = "03:44";
```

What you can do is Create a Date formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormatter f = new SimpleDateFormatter("HH:mm");
```

Than create a date object:

```
Date d = f.parse(yourDate);
```

Do the same with the date you get from your SQLite table in a new Date object:

```
Date d2 = f.parse(dateFromTable);
```

Now Compare dates by simply

```
d.compareTo(d2)
```

Comment: i am beginner.i am working on train schedule project.so when an user choose a time from time picker acording you i if i  firstly store in yourdate string and then set it and parse it in dateformat ok but now this yourDate value i want to compare many column of time value and as result i want to show to user only ahead time.let us take an example   :: if user select 3:20 as time and i have table that contain like   time(col name):time col value:3:15  then second column name:time col value 3:25 and so on so i want that user only show 3:25 train and so on not start from 3:15 bcz user enter 3:20.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is something strange in your table, as you seem to declare several columns with the name 'TIME'. Is that working?

```
hellodb4.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (STATION TEXT,TIME TIME,TIME TIME,TIME TIME)");
```

Anyway, if I understand your question correctly, you probably want to make the date comparison in the SQL query, right? You can use the date/time functions in SQLite:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

A query like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM time_table WHERE strftime(TIME, 'HH:MM') > ?";
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String[] params = String[] { f.format(dateFromUser) };
db.rawQuery(query, params);
```

I have not tested the code above, so you might need to modify it to work.

Comment: can you explain this code because i am beginner. can't understand that  i store the user input time value in string so how i can link to above code??   like  settime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.time);                                String str3=settime.getText().toString().trim();so user input time i stored in str3.

Comment: If you already have the user input you just use it in the format(String) function:

Comment: SimpleDateFormatter in programming it said that change to simpledateformat.can you explain your code step by step like how i link user input time button to above code????

Comment: If you have the time already as a string, just replace in the query, then you only need to replace the query parameter with it:

   `String query = "SELECT * FROM time_table WHERE strftime(TIME, 'HH:MM') > ?";`
    `String dateFromUser = settime.getText();`
    `db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { dateFromUser } );`

If you have doubts regarding the rawQuery method, check the [doc]{http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html}